Office Outlook Add-In and OAuth2
Problem:
I am trying to write an Office Add-In using TypeScript and a unified manifest for Microsoft 365. I want to log in to a website using OAuth2 to make API requests on that site, but I can't open the link. I keep getting this error: "Dialog failed to open: The domain of the URL is not included in the AppDomains element in the manifest and is not a subdomain of the source location."
My question:
How can I open this link with an Office Add-In button and log in with OAuth2?
I need a detailed guide to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance.
I have already tried importing the OAuth2 library, but errors occurred. Additionally, I tried opening the link, but I always get the same error.

You need to add your Auth2 Domain url in your the manifest file
for example in XML manifest by default url is http://www.contoso.com you can replace it with your Auth2 domain url or you can add a new url
for example https://login.microsoftonline.com for Microsoft login Microsoft domain url.
In unified manifest you need to change websiteUrl value https://www.contoso.com to your Auth2 app domain url.



Ok thanks. But how does this whole OAuth2 princip work? How can i program it in a office add-in?

Office js add-in are same like website
